# What is the probability that every element were chosen at least one time?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There is set with 20 elements, we take one, write what we get, put element back to set, we do this operation 21 times. What is the probability that every element were chosen at least one time?

My solution:

Order of sample space is $20^{21}$. Our desired event happens when one element is chosen twice and other elements are chosen once.

Choose an element $x$ which will be chosen twice ${20 \choose 1}$

Choose two moments when $x$ will be chosen ${21 \choose 2}$

There are $19$ elements and $19$ choosing lefts, we have to choose every element exatcly once so $19!$

So the probability is $\frac{{20 \choose 1}{21 \choose 2}19!}{20^{21}}$

Comment: This is  ok ! $\;\;$:)